# row ID error after deleting a row in Android SQLite database

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, sqlite

I have created a program based on this [Deleting entry from SQLite database](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRId7kvLyJk&list=PL33384E9848C4F55E) tutorial.

Everything works fine except one thing. While I have added new rows to the SQLite Database it worked perfectly, but as soon as I deleted one of these rows, the rest of the ROWID haven't updated itself, just continued counting as usually.

For example I have added five rows, than I deleted the third one so the others should rewrite themselves to 1,2,3,4. But the ROWIDs remained: 1,2,4,5

I was looking for this problem on the Internet, and I found out that I should somehow put the remained rows to a new database and then back and it should be all right. But I have never worked with SQL before, so I don't know the code how to fix the problem.
Could you please tell me, how to solve my problem?

Here is my database code:

```
public class HotOrNot {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "persons_name";
public static final String KEY_HOTNESS = "persons_hotness";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "HotOrNotdb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "peopleTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + 
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_HOTNESS + " TEXT NOT NULL);"



                );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
public HotOrNot(Context c){
    ourContext = c;
}

public HotOrNot open() throws SQLException{
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}

public long createEntry(String name, String hotness) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    cv.put(KEY_HOTNESS, hotness);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}

public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HOTNESS};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iHotness = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_HOTNESS);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName) + " " + c.getString(iHotness) + "\n";
    }
    return result;
}

public String getName(long l) throws SQLException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HOTNESS};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + l, null, null, null, null);
    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String name = c.getString(1);
        return name;
    }
    return null;
}

public String getHotness(long l) throws SQLException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HOTNESS};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + l, null, null, null, null);
    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String hotness = c.getString(2);
        return hotness;
    }
    return null;
}

public void updateEntry(long lRow, String mName, String mHotness) throws SQLException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_NAME, mName);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_HOTNESS, mHotness);
    ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_ROWID + "=" + lRow, null);
}

public void deleteEntry(long lRow1) throws SQLException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + lRow1, null);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need the rows to be sequential?  The id is just that, an id.  It shouldn't matter to your application if its 1 or 1,000,000 as it only serves as a unique identifier for that rows data.

Comment: Because I have written a do while cycle which goes through all the rows. My "while" condition is that as soon as the 2nd column equals to = "" it has to stop. But now it stops at column 3 and it doesn't read the 4th and 5th columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **ID** (primary key)in database is unique for each record and it is assigned once.

They can not be changed later for any record.

So if you delete any record then other **rowId** will not get affected.

The result you are getting is Expected Result. Don't Worry.

Comment: Ok, but then is there a possibility to make it sequential? I mean not the rowid, but something else. Maybe something like an integer i set to 0 and with every addition the i would rise with 1 and when you delete a row every i after the deleted row would increase by 1